# Python GTK - DrawingArea with opacity

Tags: python, gtk

I'm working on a transparent window which includes a DrawingArea widget, which gets on top with a solid background color, but I want to keep it transparent. I've tried everything, unfortunately the docs are a bit dated (with PyGTK on the top results). Other things I've done is connecting its `draw` event as I'm doing it with the window, but with no success.

Of course I need the square to be shown, so I just need the background color to transparent. I've also tried with `modify_bg`, but I only manage to set it to solid colors.

Here's what I have so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
import cairo

class GWin (Gtk.Window):
  def __init__(self):
    super(GWin, self).__init__()
    self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
    self.screen = self.get_screen()
    self.visual = self.screen.get_rgba_visual()
    if self.visual != None and self.screen.is_composited():
      self.set_visual(self.visual)
    self.connect("draw", self.on_win_draw)
    self.set_app_paintable(True)
    self.show_all()
    self.draw_area = Gtk.DrawingArea()
    self.draw_area.add_events(Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK) 
    self.draw_area.connect('draw', self.begin_draw)
    self.draw_area.show()
    self.add(self.draw_area)

  def begin_draw(self, draw_area, cairo_context):
    cairo_context.rectangle(20, 20, 120, 120)
    cairo_context.stroke()

  def on_win_draw(self, widget, cr):
    cr.set_source_rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.1)
    cr.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_SOURCE)
    cr.paint()
    cr.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_OVER)

win = GWin()
win.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `cairo.Context` source rgba before creating the rectangle. Here is the code, the edited line marked with `### ADDED THIS LINE`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
import cairo

class GWin (Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GWin, self).__init__()
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.screen = self.get_screen()
        self.visual = self.screen.get_rgba_visual()
        if self.visual != None and self.screen.is_composited():
            self.set_visual(self.visual)
        self.connect("draw", self.on_win_draw)
        self.set_app_paintable(True)
        self.show_all()
        self.draw_area = Gtk.DrawingArea()
        self.draw_area.add_events(Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK) 
        self.draw_area.connect('draw', self.begin_draw)
        self.draw_area.show()
        self.add(self.draw_area)

    def begin_draw(self, draw_area, cairo_context):
        cairo_context.set_source_rgba(1, 1, 1, 1)  ### ADDED THIS LINE
        cairo_context.rectangle(20, 20, 120, 120)
        cairo_context.stroke()

    def on_win_draw(self, widget, cr):
        cr.set_source_rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.1)
        cr.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_SOURCE)
        cr.paint()
        cr.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_OVER)

win = GWin()
win.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
Gtk.main()
```